# How to validate node-crone jobs run even when server restarts

Tags: node.js, cron, forever

This must be a generic question.
I looked and found **node-cron** to be a popular choice to run cron tasks in node.
I know about forever ensuring the node process will restart after crashes.
The question remains what happens after the vm restart? How can I guarantee node + forever + cron tasks are running?
 Do I have to run system start scripts (pain) or is there a way to avoid that and configure it through node or a node module?
Cheers
Ajar

Comment: Such system reboot tasks should be registered in the system. So, you should register system cron jobs to run at reboot, or init scripts, or use `supervisord` daemon (a Python program) which provides convenient and easy to use functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use a database like [REDIS](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) which is very fast to keep the status of your jobs. Find status of your job after restart

Answer (score 0):

As @eye above said, and then the suggestion about REDIS these are two options:

1. Daemonize the service
2. Use Redis
3. Combo

I would humbly suggest, though you may not like it or cannot use it, to check out [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). This would solve all the problems above. You can also use REDIS as well with PM2.